# Cambiar fecha a español en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como bien saben, rails en su defecto pone todo en ingles, eh hecho un scaffold y eh incluido un dato tipo **"date"** quiero que mi fecha se muestre en español ya que mal que el resto de la pagina este en español y la fecha en ingles, en mi formulario tengo :

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <h5><%= f.input :fecha, as: :date,start_year: Date.today.year-5,
                                            end_year: Date.today.year,
                                            order:[:year,:month, :day], :hint=>"Inicio de la fecha"%></h5>
  </div>
```

En si solo serian los meses que son quienes se muestran en ingles y los quiero en español, muchas gracias.

Comment: En la [documentación](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization) sale como configurar tu aplicación para otros idiomas. Para español, deberías usar `:es` y agregar [la internacionalización requerida](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml) a tu proyecto. En caso que estés usando una gema específica para generar el input de calendario, revisa su documentación, en general sale como agregar el formato de otro idioma.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] y complementar tu pregunta todo lo que necesites. Idealmente no borres, sólo añade cosas

Answer (score 0):

Para traducciones debes generar un archivo en:

`config/locales/es.yml`

Luego en este archivo agregas algo asi

```
es:
  date: # there is also a section for datetime and time
    formats:
      custom_format: "aqui defines tu formato"
```

Lo llamas asi:

```
I18n.localize(Date.today, format: :custom_format)
```

y por último en `config/application.rb` debes agregar esto:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = 'es'
```

esta última línea coloca el valor es por default (debes reiniciar tu servidor).

Aqui te dejo informacion de como darle formato a una fecha [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime),también te recomiendo implementar esta gema [i18n rails](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) o por lo menos tomar el archivo [es.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml)

Comment: Hola @mariovzc no entiendo donde depo poner el codigo para llamarlo ? en la vista ? para llamarlo asi :   {I18n.localize(Date.today, format: :custom_format)}

Comment: @STIVENARTEAGAESPITIA algo asi:  `<%= f.date_field :matriculation_date, as: :date, value: I18n.localize(Date.today, format: :custom_format)%>`

Comment: Hola Stiven, mariovzc puedes utilizar la manera breve de llamar al I18n que sería colocando ```l Date.today, format: :default``` Saludos!